# YouTube videos not playing in chromeless player in Flash using Zend_GData_Youtube class in PHP to pass results to flash (Works fine on Mac Safari??)

Tags: flash, firefox, safari, youtube-api, zend-gdata

I have been noticing some strange (but consistent) behavior with the 
chromeless YouTube Player API. I have a Flash AS2 SWF that uses 
cueVideoById() to show the thumbnail images of videos which works 
great. When the thumb is clicked I call playVideo() to play the 
video.

For some videos this loads the video and when I look at the traffic 
using firebug in Firefox I can see that a get_video call is being 
made 
to www.youtube.com - for example - 
http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=LYhrYHmUPn0&t=vjVQa1PpcFPiP... 
For some other videos though this never works and in firebug i do not 
see any call being made - there is no get_video request when I try to 
play the video. 
I have tested this on both Windows and Mac machines and here are some 
observations -

1. Safari 5.0 (7533.16) Running on Windows XP
   First - Tried to load the following video - video_id=ZaI2IlHwmgQ - A 
   get_video_info request is made but the video never loads and does not 
   play. 
   Second - Tried to load the following video - video_id=LYhrYHmUPn0 - 
   get_video_info request made AND videoplayback request made to 
   v3.lscache7.c.youtube.com AND get_video request made to www.youtube.com 
   AND 4x s requests made to s2.youtube.com and set_awsome request made 
   to www.youtube.com
2. Mozilla Firefox running on Windows XP - tried to load the same 
   videos with exactly the same results.
3. Safari on Mac loaded all videos without any problems, I did not 
   find a video that would not play
4. Mozilla Firefox on mac had similar problems where some videos 
   would load and others would not.

   1. On a windows PC using Internet Explorer the videos load and play fine.

It appears that for those that do not load the get_video_info request 
is being made but the videoplayback and get_video requests do not get 
made.

This seems to be a problem with Safari and Firefox on a PC only. What are the similarities between Flash Player running in these browsers that is different to it running in Internet Explorer?

Has anyone found a fix for this problem or know what might be causing 
it. 
thanks

Comment: It would be a lot easier to help you, if you supply the code involved in playing the video.

Comment: *Safari* and *Firefox* have the similarity of both being browser, that's about it :(  Have you checked your *Flash Player* versions on both browsers? Are you getting any *browser* **JavaScript errors** on your pages after you notice this phenomenon you've mentioned?